# Hibernate is using wrong table for join when inheritence strategy is InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a base JPA Entity defined like so (I'm using *Hibernate 5.4.25.final* implementation):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Attributes")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BaseAttributeEntity {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "containerId")
    private ContainerEntity containerEntity;
}
```

And 2 inheriting entities, both similar to the below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SpecialAttributes")
public class SpecialAttributeEntity extends BaseAttributeEntity {
   // ... some more properties
}
```

The table structure is similar to what's described in the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-inheritance-joined-table), with id column defined on all 3 tables.

I also have another entity containing collections of the 2 entities, something like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Container")
public class ContainerEntity {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "containerEntity")
    private Set<SpecialAttributeEntity> specialAttributes = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "containerEntity")
    private Set<AnotherSpecialAttributeEntity> anotherSpecialAttributes = new HashSet<>();
}
```

When I try to run some searching logic and fetch `ContainerEntity`s I get the below error from the underlying sql:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column specialattr0_.containerId does not exist
  Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "specialattr0_1_.containerId".
```

The underlying sql Hibernate uses for fetching (I left only the `from` statement because that's where the problem lies):

```
from 
  "Service"."SpecialAttributes" specialattr0_ 
  inner join "Service"."Attributes" specialattr0_1_ on specialattr0_."id" = specialattr0_1_."id" 
  left outer join "Service"."Containers" containeren1_ on customattr0_1_."containerId" = containeren1_."id"
```

Basically the problem is that both of the "attributes" entities are joined using the `containerId` column, which is defined in the base class DB table, but Hibernate tries to make the `join` but using the column from the children classes DB tables (where it obviously does not exist...).

I tried, but still haven't found a solution for this. How can I direct Hibernate to use the right table? Preferably using the standard specification?

Thank you!

Comment: Your class `ContainerEntity` has two fields with the same name `customAttributes` that is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply cannot use `@OneToMany(mappedBy)` in this particular case due to a limitation in older Hibernate versions in combination with using the subtype. You should switch to

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "containerEntity")
private Set<BaseAttributeEntity> attributes = new HashSet<>();

private Set<SpecialAttributeEntity> specialAttributes;
private Set<AnotherSpecialAttributeEntity> anotherSpecialAttributes;

// Put respective instances into separate collections on load
@PostLoad
void postLoad() {
    this.specialAttributes = attributes.stream().filter(a instanceof SpecialAttributeEntity).collect(toSet());
    this.anotherSpecialAttributes = attributes.stream().filter(a instanceof AnotherSpecialAttributeEntity).collect(toSet());
}

// Controlled write access
public void addAttribute(BaseAttributeEntity a) {
    if (a instanceof SpecialAttributeEntity) {
        specialAttributes.add(a);
    } else {
        anotherSpecialAttributes.add(a);
    }
    attributes.add(a);
}
public void removeAttribute(BaseAttributeEntity a) {
    if (a instanceof SpecialAttributeEntity) {
        specialAttributes.remove(a);
    } else {
        anotherSpecialAttributes.remove(a);
    }
    attributes.remove(a);
}

// Provide read-only access
public Set<SpecialAttributeEntity> getSpecialAttributes() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(specialAttributes);
}
public Set<AnotherSpecialAttributeEntity> getAnotherSpecialAttributes() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(anotherSpecialAttributes);
}
```